# debugging a multithreaded program with valgrind and gdb

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging

Premise, I'm using Eclipse.
In my quest for the debug of a multithreaded application i first ran valgrind memcheck that gave me a bunch of errors, couldn't identify which lines of code these errors originated from.
I then created a profile to use valgrind on Debug build, it gave me an error
"Invalid read of size 1" that pointed to a line in the source code which allowed me to fix it. Now valgrind runs on the Debug build are giving me no errors, but if I try to run valgrind on the Release build i get errors, which cannot pinpoint.

```
==5083== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==5083==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5083==    by 0x400F67: main (in /home/crysis/workspace/ReliableUPDserver/Release/ReliableUPDserver)
==5083== 
==5083== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
==5083==    at 0x4C29F90: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5083==    by 0x400FA1: main (in /home/crysis/workspace/ReliableUPDserver/Release/ReliableUPDserver)
==5083== 
==5083== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 4
==5083==    at 0x4C2C080: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5083==    by 0x400F3E: main (in /home/crysis/workspace/ReliableUPDserver/Release/ReliableUPDserver)
==5083==
```

How come these errors appear only with the Release build? What can i do to get more information?
Also, my multithreaded program hangs somewhere, is this the right way to try find out where the problem is?

Comment: Does Helgrind, http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html help somewhere?

Comment: @Suvarna Nope i try a run using helgrind instead of memcheck, no errors either with the Debug and Release build

Comment: Try to run your code sequenced, that is in single-threaded mode and debug it until you face no more errors, then turn to the mutli-threaded build.

Comment: Try enabling debug info generation in release build.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky thx, that worked, now I located the errors on the main.

Comment: Are you supplying the argument --leak-check=full when you run valgrind?